# Injecting the RealmsManager

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-rs

I'm writing `ContainerRequestFilter` to inspect request headers and provide a pluggable authentication mechanism which would iterate the configured AS security realms (e.g. Glassfish) and provide a custom `SecurityContext`.
I'm trying to inject the `RealmsManager` (defined in `com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.RealmsManager`[1]), which is annotated as `@Singleton` in the `ContainerRequestFilter`. This is my code:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject
    RealmsManager rm;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        if (rm != null) {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.ok("OKAY").build());

        } else {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.ok("NULL").build());
        }
}
```

but I get this error while deploying the WAR:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied
    dependencies for type RealmsManager with qualifiers @Default
    at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject
```

How can I inject the `RelamsManager` singleton in a `ContainerRequestFilter`?

[1] Here's the source of `RealmsManager`: https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/trunk/main/nucleus/security/core/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/security/auth/realm/RealmsManager.java